# Babylonian Algorithm with C++ unable to get loop to run

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, math, numerical-methods

Is the refusal for the program to produce the result a consequence of it unable to get into the loop?

Please find the below code for more information.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x, squareroot, oldsquareroot, counter=0;
    cout << "Enter a positive number: " ;
    cin >> x ;
    {
        for (oldsquareroot = x/2; abs(squareroot-oldsquareroot) >= 1e-9 &&   abs(squareroot - oldsquareroot)>=(1E-8*x);counter++ )
        {
             squareroot = (squareroot+x/squareroot)/2;
        }

    }
    cout << setprecision(15);
    cout << "The value of the squareroot is:" << squareroot << endl;
    cout << "The number of interations required for the computation is:" <<  counter << endl;
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Describe the output you get, i.e. nothing at all, not what you expected, etc. Also, use the debugger to check if the loop is entered. You don't need a whole community to check program execution.
On a side note: comparing double values, *especially* small ones like that, is a very bad idea for conditional expressions.

Answer (score 1):

There were some mistakes. 
Now it works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x, squareroot, oldsquareroot, counter = 0;
    cout << "Enter a positive number: ";
    cin >> x;
    {
        squareroot = x; // fixed error 1: using of uninitialized variable.
        for (oldsquareroot = x / 2; abs(squareroot - oldsquareroot) >=  1e-9 && abs(squareroot - oldsquareroot) >= (1E-8*x); counter++)
        {
            oldsquareroot = squareroot;// fixed eror 2: oldsquareroot is not changed in the loop and can't exit.
            squareroot = (squareroot + x / squareroot) / 2;
        }
    }
    cout << setprecision(15);
    cout << "The value of the squareroot is:" << squareroot << endl;
    cout << "The number of interations required for the computation is:" << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I hope that it will help you.

Comment: I'd downvote that becaute it does other people's homewore and it doesn't explain the error in any way.